# Delete rows and columns in multiple worksheet using Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Hundreds of xlsx files in a directory are imported into a MS Access 2010 Database.

I've to clean the worksheet before importing.

Question is: How to delete all rows that have no data in column A and all columns starting from the O to XFD?

The code below works but for one file a time.
[image]

All red must be deleted.

```
Private Sub Comand_Click()
    Dim FullPath As String
    Dim oXL As Object, oWb As Object, oWs As Object
    FullPath = "D:\Access\_Test_XlsImport\FileName.xlsx"
    Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set oWb = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FullPath)
    Set oWs = oWb.Sheets("Worksheet_name")
    oXL.Visible = True

    With oWs
        .Columns("O:XFD").Delete
        .Rows("xx:xx").Delete ' <---problem to identify the starting point to delete below..
    End With
    oWb.Save

CleanUp:
    oWb.Close False
    oXL.Quit
    Set oWb = Nothing
    Set oXL = Nothing
    Set oWs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write a loop? Or how to identify the first non-empty row? How do YOU define "empty" - the whole row has to be empty or a specific cell in column?

Comment: Exactly Mr. dbmitch a loop that works for all resident files resident in the dir
Column header go for each single files from A1 to N1
I Validate the row by the first 3 characters of the string stored in the first cell  in the column A

Answer (score 0):

I would pull out the oXL variable and make it global to your module so you only open it once.

Then put the other Excel objects into the subroutine that cleans the worksheets

Something like this should work - substitute your folder for the constant
The DIR command just matches all files that match the xlsx file spec and processes each of them in the loop

> Just a warning - there is no check for files that have NO Data in
>   column A - if that happens the program will continue until all rows
>   have been exhausted.
>
> **EDIT - Modified to remove all empty rows up until last non-empty cell**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


' Use these as global
Private oXL As Object

Private Sub Comand_Click()

    Const SEARCH_FOLDER     As String = "C:\Databases\"
    Const EXCEL_FILES       As String = "*.xlsx"

    Dim FullPath As String

    Dim strExcelFolder  As String
    Dim strFilename     As String

    ' Open Excel
    Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oXL.Visible = True

    strFilename = Dir(SEARCH_FOLDER & EXCEL_FILES)
    While strFilename <> ""
        ProcessExcelFile SEARCH_FOLDER, strFilename
        strFilename = Dir()
    Wend

CleanUp:
    oXL.Quit
    Set oXL = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessExcelFile(strExcelFolder As String, strExcelFile As String)

    Dim oWb As Object, oWs As Object
    Dim strFullPath As String

    Dim LastRow As Long

    strFullPath = strExcelFolder & strExcelFile
    Set oWb = oXL.Workbooks.Open(strFullPath)
    Set oWs = oWb.Sheets(1)

    With oWs
        LastRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

        .Columns("O:XFD").Delete

        ' Select All rows in Column A up to last filled row
        .Range(“A1:A" & LastRow).Select

       ' Delete all rows with empty cell in A - up to last filled row
        oXL.Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

        .Save
        .Close False
    End With

    Set oWb = Nothing
    Set oWs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Mr. db mitch I think you very close to solve. Just an error runtime 438 at this line  Set oWb = oXL.Workbooks.Open(strFullPath). Microsoft access and office 14.0 object library are both set in the references

Comment: Remove the "& "\" " from `strFullPath = strExcelFolder & "\" & strExcelFile` - updated answer

Comment: Done it today at office Mr dbmitch, error doesn't run but nothing change in to the files.
I want to clarify that all code you written is under the event "on click".
At the moment testing just with one file resident in the dir

Comment: Ok I understood...code work! But begins to delete the rows from cell A1 and not from the first blank cell in column A!

Comment: I also modified "Loop   oWb.Save   oWb.Close" if not runtime error 438 comes at this lines.

Comment: Would be better that each cell in column A with no data the row was eliminated...I tried to modify the code in every way but I'm not so good

Comment: You aren't making much sense. Best to show sample of data and then example of what you expect it to look like afterwards. Edit your question. The code should be in your module

Comment: Original question.edited and example posted mr. dbmitch. Hoping is now clear

Comment: Deleting rows after the last filled row doesn't make sense - you'll always have empty rows at the end. I can adjust it so all empty rows up to end of data are deleted

Comment: Agree Mr dbmitch. When will be possible for you. I appreciate your help and your patience.

Comment: Hi Mr. dbmitch! I'm frustrated and disappointed. During this time I tried the code that you have created but are not able to make it work. So I applied the first solution

Comment: Are you asking a question?